# Using outweighed as a past verb

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, grammaticality

I want to say that we give more consideration to quality over quantity. I am not sure of my understanding of the word. Is my use of outweighed here correct?

> We outweighed food's quality over quantity.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is not. You'd need to say something like, "When judging, we gave more points to food quality than food quantity." I am assuming that you are talking about some contest.

Answer (score 1):

No, your use of **[outweighed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outweigh)** is not correct here.  To *outweigh* means "to be greater or more significant than".  So saying "We outweighed food's quality" means "we were more important than food's quality"!  If you want to use the word *outweighed* you would have to say something like

> The food's quality *outweighed* its quantity.

If you want to talk about how we gave more consideration to quality, you might say

> We *gave more weight* to food's quality than its quantity

or maybe

> We *weighed* food's quality *more heavily* than its quantity